# Generate typescript type from string value

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create typescript types from string values?
Something like this

```
const typeName = 'number';
type myType = typeName;
const x: myType = 5;
```

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: @Michael, I get the types from an api response, and need to dynamically generate interfaces using those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really possible to go from a type name to a type in typescript, even for built-in types. You might consider creating a mapping interface between names and types. Then going from name to type would require a simple type index query:

```
interface TypeMap {
    number: number,
    string: string,
    boolean: boolean,
    // etc
}
const typeName = 'number';
type myType = TypeMap[typeof typeName];
const x: myType = 5;
```

**Edit** We need `typeof typeName` (instead of `typeName` in `TypeMap[typeof typeName]`) because type index queries work with types (not with values such as variables). We can however get the type of any variable using the `typeof` type operator.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks. Can you clarify the `typeof typeName` part? Isn't it supposed to be `string` in this case?

Comment: @HaykSafaryan added an explanation, let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Dynamically generating types for an API at runtime isn't going to be very useful, at that point it's too late and you may as well be using `any`

It sounds like what you want to do is generate types for the API as a pre-build step.

There's a few options for this, one is to write a specification of the API using a format such as openapi3 and use a code generation tool to generate the API client / glue code. This is an approach I've taken on a number of projects, and it works fairly well but you do have to fight the generator at times.

There are also tools that will generate JSON schema from a JSON blob, and in turn generate typescript types from JSON schema. Again they aren't perfect, but often this can be a quick and easy way to scaffold types for an API, that you can then manually refine.

Ref:
https://openapi.tools/
https://quicktype.io/typescript/